# Testing git connection in php using SSH

Tags: php, shell, ssh

I am trying to programmatically test a git connection using PHP/SSH. For testing purposes I have made a fork of the Spoon-Knife repo and made it private and add the public key to my GitHub account. I am trying to establish a connection to that repository. As a safety precaution, that is not self-evident for this use case, I am saving the private key encrypted in a DB and temporarily placing the key in a `$str_private_key_path` file that is removed right after executing the following command.

```php
$cmd_list = "git ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/$str_username/$str_repository --config core.sshCommand='ssh -i $str_private_key_path -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' > $log_file_name";
$str_exec = shell_exec($cmd_list);
```

The log file exists but is empty as an error doesn't return from shell_exec, an error or no output returns `null`.

If I don't remove the private key file, I can see the file contains the private key and when I just execute the first part of the command using a key that is part of the OS I get the result I would expect.

```php
git ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/Sl4rtyb4rtf4st/Spoon-Knife // commit ID    HEAD
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

PS (edited)

---

When I try using authentication with an external file, by doing the following:

```
$ssh -i private_key_file -T git@github.com
```

I get this response. Which indicates that the problem is not with the external file or the ssh (`-i`) option:

```
Hi Sl4rtyb4rtf4st! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

To me this only leaves a problem with the following part of the shell command:

```
--config core.sshCommand='...
```

PPS

---

Reading the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand), it would seem that the `ls-remote` can not be used in combination with the `core.sshCommand` command. Performing the same command with `clone` instead of `ls-remote` works as expected.

So that means I need a different method to test the connection to GitHub.

### *SOLUTION*

---

If I do the following I can test the connection to GitHub. Not sure if it will work with other git providers like Bitbucket.

```php
$cmd_list = "ssh -i $str_private_key_path -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T git@github.com 2>&1 | tee $log_file_name";
$str_exec = shell_exec($cmd_list);
```

Doing this places the "Hi Username! You've successfully authenticated, ..." message in the `$log_file_name` file. Using `>` instead of `2>&1 | tee` did the same when done in the terminal, but didn't work when executing from within PHP.

Obviously doesn't work for deploy keys on individual repositories, but that is a problem for the future.

Comment: Does tihs help - https://github.community/t/does-not-provide-shell-access/2728/2

Comment: @RamanSailopal I'm not trying to get ssh access to my GitHub account. I just would like to perform a single action, and as I stated, I can do just fine in a Linux shell without the file authentication. But that does not work when calling it from with the private key in a separate file.

Comment: @Sl4rtib4rtf4st please follow these steps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-github-with-ssh-secure-shell/

Comment: @kuldeepraj Thanks, that was not a solution but it did give me the idea to just use `ssh -T git@github.com` as a connection test in `shell_exec()`. Quite obvious come to think of it...